# Is it possible to recover a deleted chat history

Tags: skype

I deleted all my conversation histories by mistake using Tools from menu, Conversations, IM SMS, and then delete history.  I was wondering if there is there any way of recovering this, and whether it is stored in the cloud?  There is no back up of the main.db file on my computer.  All the chat history has been deleted.  But if the chat history is stored on other users who have participated in this chat then am I not able to recover their data to my computer?

Comment: That's a really odd mistake at best. You won't be able to recover your history just because the messages are still stored in the history of other users. As you explicitly chose to delete it you might be unable to recover it. Have a look for backups of your main.db, those might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I agree it is an odd mistake.  I was familiar with removing or editing individual messages.  There was a number of messages of mine I wanted to remove.  I suppose I assumed by clearing the history it would remove all messages from the history of other users as well.  My error.